# Omission of was

Tags: sentence-construction, reduced-relative-clauses

> Court dismissed the plea filed by the victim.

Above is the original sentence read by me in news paper

Can I write the sentence as below,

> Court dismissed the plea (which was) filed by the victim.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The original form

> Court dismissed the plea **filed by the victim**.

is a "reduced relative clause", which you have expanded as

> Court dismissed the plea **which was filed by the victim**.

This reduction is explained at

[Thoughtco "reduced clause"](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107)
"Reduce to an Adjective Phrase"

Comment: This is a common practice in print reporting; it is also anecdotally fairly common in speech in some areas.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Court dismissed the plea **which was** filed by the victim."*

Here,*"which was filed by the victim"* is a relative **clause** modifying its antecedent *"the plea"* in the main clause.

You can omit the part *"which was"* to form *a reduced relative clause* :

> *"Court dismissed the plea filed by the victim."*

Here, the adjective **phrase**, *"filed by the victim"*, serves as the postmodifier of the NP *"the plea"*.

Therefore, both sentences are correct. The postmodifier of the NP (the plea)  is **a finte clause** in one sentence and **a phrase or a non-finite clause** in another sentence.

In modern grammar, the adjective phrase *"filed by the victim"* is treated as the **Past participle non-finite clause**.